# Small syntax error with miles-to-kilograms converter exercise

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get some practice in before my Intro to C++ class begins this Fall. I was going through some exercises in my textbook and I'm stuck on a miles-to-kilograms conversion exercise. Aparently my compiler says that it's expecting a ';' before line 7 but I don't understand where a ';' could possibly be placed before line 7?

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
 double miles;
 double kilograms == miles * 1.609;
 cout << "How many miles away is your destination? ";
 cin >> miles;
 cout << "Your destination is " << kilograms << " kilograms away!";
 }
```

Comment: `double kilograms == miles * 1.609;` should be `double kilograms = miles * 1.609;` as `==` is for comparisons

Comment: When I change '==' to '=' though, I am given two error messages:

"Using unitialized memory 'miles'
and
"unitialized local variable 'miles' used"

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Miles are distance, kilograms are mass... Please change it to kilometers...

Comment: @PhantomDiclonius Can you please explain how conversion of distances or length to masses should make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`double kilograms == miles * 1.609;` should be `double kilograms = miles * 1.609;` as `==` is used for comparisons / conditional statements.

Another problem, you should place `kilograms = miles * 1.609;` right after `cin >> miles;` because right now, it does the calculation on an empty variable and will likely create another error later, or just return 0.

Sidenote: the person who made the question confused kilograms for kilometres, so just ignore that.

EDIT: On the `using uninitialized variable...`, make sure to change `double miles;` to `double miles = 0;` as C++ (and many more languages) requires variables to be assigned before they're accessed.

Comment: I moved "kilograms = miles * 1.609;" like you suggested and it works now. Thank you.

Comment: _@Axium_ Sorry to nitpick here. `kilograms = miles * 1.609;` That's complete nosense regarding a semantical viewpoint of physics. The most appropriate we can thinik of is `kilometers = miles * 1.609;`

Comment: That’s what he meant. I just didn’t think twice about the names haha @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @Axium Well, add a side note about that into your answer.

Comment: @PhantomDiclonius _"I moved "kilograms = miles * 1.609;""_ And that still is complete nonsense. Did you confuse _kilograms_ and _kilometers_?

Comment: Still wrong. Should be a function. Multiplying zero by anything is still just zero

Comment: I'm confused. What should be a function? @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: It's `double kilograms = miles * 1.609;`. You suggested "fixing" it by init'ing `miles` to zero :D

Comment: Actually never mind you addressed that sorry :D

Comment: its all good haha

Comment: A function _would_ be more appropriate though!

Comment: That is true. However, it seems that they're only doing this once, so it could just mean more lines of code. If this was needed multiple times, I agree that making it a function would be more appropriate.

Comment: To be honest even for one use I'd recommend a function for this. It's self-documenting and a textbook case for a function. But that's just a suggestion for the OP.

Comment: I'll use that info when I'm programming. Thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit!